# Is a multivariate Beta Regression appropriate for modelling multiple dependent variables where each variable is a percentage?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, beta-distribution, beta-regression

I have a dataset with multiple predictors, some discrete and some percentages. My response variable is essentially 3 categories: percentage of high, medium and low life satisfaction, or maybe they are 3 different responses? My question is essentially, what is the best way to model this using a GLM?

Comment: Not an expert in GLMs, so in lieu of a full answer, have you looked into Dirichlet regression?

Comment: Yes, that's near exactly what i'm looking for, thankyou